# How to use StringIO fuction on a Dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a data frame with two columns(Service Name,Port Number) where values in  Service Name is a object and port number is a int value. when  i tried to convert them into a StringIO format i am getting TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame.

I tried to convert the data frame into string with `str(data)` StringIo converts the values, but when i am trying to loop through i get the following error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

This is the fist 12 rows in my file.

```
Service Name    Port Number
Port_0  0
tcpmux  1
compressnet 2
compressnet 3
Unassigned  4
rje 5
Unassigned  6
echo    7
Unassigned  8
discard 9
Unassigned  10
systat  11
Unassigned  12
```

SO the loop i'm tying to run

```
#converting the "-" into a range and adding back to the data frame

import csv

def extend_ports(file, delim=','):
   handle = csv.reader(file, delimiter=delim)
   yield next(handle)  # skip header
   for row in handle:
      try:
         service_name, port_number = row
      except ValueError:
          print(f"Could not parse line '{row}'")
          raise
      if '-' not in port_number:
         yield [service_name, port_number]  # simple result
      else:
         start, end = map(int, port_number.split('-'))
         for port in map(str, range(start, end+1)):
            yield [service_name, port]  # expanded result

# get the result
result = list(extend_ports(data3))
```

This code is to convert "-" symbol into a range where all the ports numbers are added back into a data frame with its service name ie 272-276 mapped to "portx" will be expanded to 272,273,274,275,276 and mapped to "portx.

I think the error message when i try to loop is more important than the code here.

I have solved this problem the hard way. the input i gave ..

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""\
Service Name,Port Number
pt-tls,271
pt-tls,271
Unassigned,272-279
http-mgmt,280
http-mgmt,280
personal-link,281
personal-link,281
cableport-ax,282
cableport-ax,282
rescap,283
rescap,283
corerjd,284
corerjd,284
Unassigned,285
fxp,286
fxp,286
k-block,287
k-block,287
Unassigned,288-307
novastorbakcup,308
novastorbakcup,308
""")
```

with the above code i got the results as

```
['Service Name', 'Port Number']
['pt-tls', '271']
['pt-tls', '271']
['Unassigned', '272']
['Unassigned', '273']
['Unassigned', '274']
['Unassigned', '275']
['Unassigned', '276']
['Unassigned', '277']
...
['Unassigned', '306']
['Unassigned', '307']
['novastorbakcup', '308']
['novastorbakcup', '308']
```

The above result is what i want from the data frame.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data is `,` separated...not `\t` use --> `result = list(extend_ports(data, delim=','))` ?

Comment: @Rakesh Its a typo. i have tried both.

Comment: Works when I use `result = list(extend_ports(data, delim=','))` are you using python2?

Comment: @Rakesh nop i am using python 3. both gives the same error (**ValueError:** not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)). i am loading the data from a csv file as a pandas data frame. please read the second part of the question for more clarification.

Comment: @Rakesh Try loading from csv and run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works from csv file also.

**Demo:**

```
import csv

def extend_ports(file, delim=','):
   handle = csv.reader(file, delimiter=delim)
   yield next(handle)  # skip header
   for row in handle:
      try:
         service_name, port_number = row
      except ValueError:
          print("Could not parse line '{row}'")
          raise
      if '-' not in port_number:
         yield [service_name, port_number]  # simple result
      else:
         start, end = map(int, port_number.split('-'))
         for port in map(str, range(start, end+1)):
            yield [service_name, port]  # expanded result

# get the result
result = list(extend_ports(open(filename, "r")))  #Open file for read. 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Service Name', 'Port Number'],
 ['pt-tls', '271'],
 ['pt-tls', '271'],
 ['Unassigned', '272'],
 ['Unassigned', '273'],
 ['Unassigned', '274'],
 ['Unassigned', '275'],
 ['Unassigned', '276'],
 ['Unassigned', '277'],
 ['Unassigned', '278'],
 ['Unassigned', '279'],
 ['http-mgmt', '280'],
 ['http-mgmt', '280'],
 ['personal-link', '281'],
 ['personal-link', '281'],
 ['cableport-ax', '282'],
 ['cableport-ax', '282'],
 ['rescap', '283'],
 ['rescap', '283'],
 ['corerjd', '284'],
 ['corerjd', '284'],
 ['Unassigned', '285'],
 ['fxp', '286'],
 ['fxp', '286'],
 ['k-block', '287'],
 ['k-block', '287'],
 ['Unassigned', '288'],
 ['Unassigned', '289'],
 ['Unassigned', '290'],
 ['Unassigned', '291'],
 ['Unassigned', '292'],
 ['Unassigned', '293'],
 ['Unassigned', '294'],
 ['Unassigned', '295'],
 ['Unassigned', '296'],
 ['Unassigned', '297'],
 ['Unassigned', '298'],
 ['Unassigned', '299'],
 ['Unassigned', '300'],
 ['Unassigned', '301'],
 ['Unassigned', '302'],
 ['Unassigned', '303'],
 ['Unassigned', '304'],
 ['Unassigned', '305'],
 ['Unassigned', '306'],
 ['Unassigned', '307'],
 ['novastorbakcup', '308'],
 ['novastorbakcup', '308']]
```

Comment: i run the code gives a different error now(TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO). my input is a tab separated                 
data Service Name Port Number(eg)
Port_0 0
tcpmux 1
compressnet 2
compressnet 3
Unassigned 4
rje 5
Unassigned 6
echo 7
Unassigned 8
discard 9
Unassigned 10
systat 11
Unassigned 12

Comment: here `filename` is the path to the csv file. Ex: `'\home\use\input.csv'`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load all the data in same loop. no need of StringIO.

Eg:-

result = list(extend_ports(open("path/filename.csv", "\t")))